# How can I index the bittorrent DHT properly for infohashes?

Tags: bittorrent, dht, webtorrent

I have this code but after 12 hours of running it only found 5 infohashes.

What can I do to increase this number?

```js
import DHT from 'bittorrent-dht';
import magnet from 'magnet-uri';
import WebTorrent from 'webtorrent';
import redis from 'redis';

const dht = new DHT();
const client = new WebTorrent();

// Create Redis client
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: 'localhost', // Update with your Redis server configuration
    port: 6379
});

redisClient.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});


// Seed nodes - Replace with actual seed nodes
const seedNodes = ['router.bittorrent.com:6881', 'dht.transmissionbt.com:6881'];
const knownTorrents = []; // store in db
const torrentQueue = []; // Queue to manage torrent fetching
const torrentFetchInterval = 10000; // Time interval between fetching torrents (in milliseconds)

client.on('torrent', (torrent) => {
    console.log(`Torrent added: ${torrent.infoHash}`);
    console.log(`Files: ${torrent.files.map((file) => file.name).join(', ')}`);
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error in WebTorrent client:', err);
});


// Example of using Redis for shared state
function updateSharedTorrentState(torrent) {
    // Storing torrent data in Redis
    redisClient.set(torrent.infoHash, JSON.stringify(torrent), redis.print);

    // Retrieving torrent data from Redis
    redisClient.get(torrent.infoHash, (err, reply) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        const sharedTorrent = JSON.parse(reply);
        console.log(sharedTorrent); // Do something with the shared torrent data
    });
}


function processTorrentQueue() {
    if (torrentQueue.length > 0) {
        const infoHashBuffer = torrentQueue.shift(); // Get the next torrent from the queue
        indexTorrent(infoHashBuffer);
    }
    setTimeout(processTorrentQueue, torrentFetchInterval);
}


function indexTorrent(infoHashBuffer) {
    const infoHash = infoHashBuffer.toString('hex');
    console.log('Torrent found:', infoHash);

    // Create a magnet URI using the info hash
    const magnetURI = `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:${infoHash}`;

    // Check if the torrent is already being tracked
    if (client.get(magnetURI)) {
        console.log(`Torrent with infoHash ${infoHash} is already being tracked.`);
        return; // Exit the function if the torrent is already added
    }

    // Fetch metadata using the WebTorrent client
    client.add(magnetURI, (torrent) => {
        console.log('Torrent metadata fetched:', torrent.name);

        // Add or update the torrent in the knownTorrents array
        const index = knownTorrents.findIndex((t) => t.infoHash === infoHash);

        if (index > -1) {
            knownTorrents[index] = {
                ...knownTorrents[index],
                name: torrent.name // Update only specific properties
            };
        } else {
            knownTorrents.push({
                infoHash,
                name: torrent.name,
                seeders: 0, // Initialize seeders and leechers
                leechers: 0
            });
        }

        // The 'tracker' event provides data from trackers
        torrent.on('tracker', (data) => {
            console.log(`Trackers for ${torrent.name} report: ${data.announce}`);
            console.log(`Seeders: ${data.complete}, Leechers: ${data.incomplete}`);

            // Update seeders and leechers in the knownTorrents array
            const torrentIndex = knownTorrents.findIndex((t) => t.infoHash === infoHash);
            if (torrentIndex > -1) {
                knownTorrents[torrentIndex] = {
                    ...knownTorrents[torrentIndex],
                    seeders: data.complete,
                    leechers: data.incomplete
                };
            }
        });



        // Removing the torrent after a short delay, as we only want the tracker info
        setTimeout(() => client.remove(magnetURI), 60000); // Adjust the delay as needed
    });

    // ...
}

// Function to add and query nodes
function joinAndTestDHTNetwork(seedNodes) {
    console.log('Joining DHT network...');

    seedNodes.forEach((seed) => {
        const [host, port] = seed.split(':');
        dht.addNode({ host, port: parseInt(port) });
    });

    // Test querying nodes after joining
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Testing DHT network by querying nodes...');
        dht.nodes.toArray().forEach((node) => {
            dht.lookup(node.id, (err, n) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(`Error querying node ${node.id}:`, err);
                } else {
                    console.log(`Node ${node.id.toString('hex')} queried successfully. Found ${n} nodes.`);
                }
            });
        });
    }, 5000); // Delay to allow time for initial network join
}

// Handling announce events
dht.on('announce', (peer, infoHashBuffer) => {
    // Add the torrent to the queue instead of processing it immediately
    torrentQueue.push(infoHashBuffer);
});

// Handling new node discovery
dht.on('node', (node) => {
    console.log(`New node discovered: ${node.host}:${node.port}`);
    // Perform a lookup for a random info hash to discover more nodes and peers
    dht.lookup(generateRandomInfoHash());
});

// Periodically perform lookups for random info hashes
setInterval(() => {
    dht.lookup(generateRandomInfoHash());
}, 10000); // Every 10 seconds, adjust as needed

// Generate a random info hash for lookup
function generateRandomInfoHash() {
    let infoHash = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        infoHash += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
    }
    return infoHash;
}

setInterval(() => {
    knownTorrents.forEach((torrent) => {
        indexTorrent(Buffer.from(torrent.infoHash, 'hex'));
    });
}, 3600000);

// Example usage
processTorrentQueue();
joinAndTestDHTNetwork(seedNodes);

dht.listen(20000, () => {
    console.log('DHT listening on port 20000');
});
```

Also it seems the `torrent.on('tracker')` never fires, nor does `client.add(magnetURI, (torrent)`

Answer (score 0):

You are very unlikely to find an active infohash through brute force alone as sha1 has a *lot* of permutations.

Use a tool like DHTSpider to get active infohashes instead: https://github.com/alanyang/dhtspider

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting infohashes that other nodes directly announce to yours. That is only a tiny fraction of the keyspace of the bittorrent DHT.

To get a wider view you'll have to implement [BEP 51](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0051.html) ([some implementation notes on that](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/master/docs/keyspace-traversal.md))

And DHT-downloaded torrents never contain trackers since the trackers are stored outside the info dictionary and the outer part is never sent over the DHT.